# Pointermove select event works but not the click select in OpenLayers 6 and Angular 7

Tags: angular, gis, openlayers

I am new to open layers. I am drawing linestring and point feature types on separate vector layers.
I took the help of [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html) from the official website and ported it to angular.

I want to select a point feature on click event. But only pointerMove select event works. I have tried playing with the tolerance factor etc. But nothing seems to work.

I wouldn't be able to publish actual code because of work policy.

The example shows different types of Select interaction.

```
this.select = new Select({
  condition: click,
  layers: [this.pointLayer]
});
```

or

```
this.select = new Select({
  condition: pointerMove,
  layers: [this.pointLayer]
});
```

`click` and `pointerMove` were imported from `'ol/events/condition';`

I added interaction using

```
this.map.addInteraction(this.select);
```

and listener

```
this.select.on('select', function (e) {

   console.log("selected features : ", e.target.getFeatures())

  });
```

Update

As per Mike's reply, I added the `ol.css` from `node_modules` to the `angular.json` styles. It is now working as expected.

Comment: That's weird, have you try the default `singleclick`?, you can do is just creating the `Select` interaction, just to check.

Comment: I have tried singleclick and altclick (as in example) as well. Both didn't work.

Comment: Are you using the ol.css?  If not it might be related to https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10732

Comment: I have experience issues when selecting points, it becomes hard to click. Try a polygon layer just to check if is something related to that issue.

Comment: @Mike you are right. The error resolved after adding the ol.css. The rest of the map was styled properly so it never occurred to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use `hitTolerance` option to increase pixel tolerance. Use default condition.